# using multiple different kafka cluster within one app

Tags: spring-kafka

This probably ins't typical setup, but due to higher decisions we endup having multiple kafka clusters within one app, multiple topics per each, and each might have different serializing strategy. Json/avro. And avro might be with confluent schema registry or using single object encoding.

Well I got it working somehow, by building my own abstractions and registry which analyzes the configuration and creates most of stuff manually, but I feel I needed to repeat stuff like topic names, schema registry url on several places multiple times just to create all needed beans. Ugly as hell.

I'd like to ask, if there is some better way and support for this I just might have overlooked.

I need to create N representations of kafka clusters, configuring it once. Configure topics respective to given kafka cluster, configure confluent schema registry for topics where applicable etc, so that I can create instance of Avro schema file, send it to KafkaTemplate and it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the complexity and how much different the configurations are, as to whether this will help, but you can override individual Kafka properties (such as bootstrap servers, deserializers, etc on the `@KafkaListener` and in each `KafkaTemplate`.

e.g.

```java
@KafkaListener(id = "two", topics = "two",
        properties = "value.deserializer:org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer")
public void listen2(byte[] in) {
    System.out.println("2: " + new String(in));
}
```

**EDIT**

The overrides can be externalized - like so:

```java
@KafkaListener(id = "so67959209", topics = "so67959209",
        properties = "${consumer.overrides.one}")
public void listen(byte[] in) {

}
```

and

```
consumer.overrides.one=bootstrap.servers:localhost:9092\n \
 key.deserializer:org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer\n \
 value.deserializer:org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
```

**IMPORTANT** The overrides are raw Kafka property names, not the bootified versions - e.g. `bootstrap.servers` Vs. Boot's `bootstrap-servers`.

Comment: so IIUC, if I have 2 kafka servers, and 20 listeners (hypothetical) and I'd like externalized configuration without recompiling, I'd need select 1 base configuration, and for every other listener I need to "override" all data from `KafkaProperties` using this `properties` parameter of `@KafkaListener`

Comment: Yes, but the overrides can easily be externalized too; see the edit.

Comment: thanks! I didn't know about this possibility. Looks kinda hacky, but good to know about this. Thank you.